# How to add a dependency to a arbitrary file to a T4 template?

Tags: c#, .net, t4

I have a T4 template that generates classes from an xml file.

How can I add a dependency between the xml file and the template file so that when the xml file is modified the template is rerun automatically without choosing "Run custom tool" from the context menu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe T4 supports automatic template transformation based on an external dependency. I agree with Marc - if you only have one external file, you could create a custom "custom tool" for your XML file or simply use [ttxgen](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/TTxGen). However, I don't think this approach scales up to a scenario where t4 template depends on more than one file. You may need to create a Visual Studio package to handle that.

Comment: Is there any way to use ttxgen from VS2010?

Answer (score 3):

How long does the tool take to execute? One lazy option might be to simply edit the csproj such that it *always* runs the tool during build (presumably via [`<Exec ... />`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8zx72cd.aspx) or a custom `targets` file) - of course, this depends on it being quick to execute.

Another way would be to write a shim that works as the "Custom Tool" in VS, and simply calls the existing exe (or whatever) with the right args. Not trivial, but doable ([see here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/VsMultipleFileGenerator.aspx?display=Print)) - I believe this then supposedly plays fairly nicely with change detection. It is actually on my list of things to do for a current project, so I'll find out soon enough...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [AutoTT](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6d3611ab-958a-4adf-92cd-dda6bbd3aa81) Visual Studio Extension.

This extension allows to configure triggers that will run a T4 template.

One of the possible triggers is a file change. In the sample configuration file in AutoTT page, the regular expression for the triggers matches all files in the specified folders (Controllers, Content), but you can change it so that it runs with a specific file only.

[Chirpy](http://chirpy.codeplex.com/releases/view/61897) is another option for doing this. And also [T4 Regenerator](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/201b7438-f362-4bd7-b8a6-1f65510a04e3), which does it in a different way.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried using [<#@ xsd](http://www.olegsych.com/2008/08/t4-xsd-directive/)?

Comment: The link is dead. Is there any other documentation on that directive?