# Auto implementing looping

Tags: c#, .net, class, extension-methods, parallel-processing

I don't know if the title makes sense, but in the app I am writing there are lots of (extension) methods. A simple example:

Objects:

```
Matter (Burn, Explode, Destroy, Freeze, Heat, Cool)
Atom (Attach, Detach)
<many more>
```

And a custom collection like:

```
ImmutableList<T>
```

And methods like these:

```
public static class Burner
{
    public static Matter Burn ( this Matter matter )
    {
        // matter is burning ...
    }
}

var matters = new ImmutableList<Matter>();
matters.Burn();
```

As you can see, Burn works on a single entity, but still appears on ImmutableList. That way I want to manage paralellization (burn in parallel) myself.

How do I do this the most performant way, or the cleanest, or the most maintainable way, or combined?

Firstly I would rather not define another extension method that takes ImmutableList inside each class (Burner, etc), because there are hundreds upon hundreds like these and they are probably gonna look the same. But I am open to ideas.

Also all code is mine, so I can change/add anything in any part of the code, not just the extension methods.

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with

```
matters.ForEach(Burner.Burn);
```

with your own implementation of `ForEach`?

Comment: Thanks but ForEach isn't parallel, and I want to manage my own parallelization to the specific needs of the app. Also I would rather the syntax in my post if possible.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your problem correctly, but what prevents you from implementing your own `ForEach` method?

Comment: I could, but I would like to have a syntax like: matters.Burn(); Otherwise there will be lots of ForEach calls in the code, not that it's a bad thing, but it's so obvious that I want a "direct" call, hence extension methods.

Comment: So you want to dynamically create extension methods to ImmutableLists depending on T and call them statically? What about using a TextTemplatingFileGenerator for this?

Comment: Thanks what's TextTemplatingFileGenerator? It's not gonna be dynamic. It's gonna be like if Burn works on Matter, so should be ImmutableList<Matter>, just same type but this collection.

Comment: TextTemplatingFileGenerator is a custom tool in Visual Studio like a ResXFileGenerator, except you write a little C# program that generates the output instead of supplying a resource file. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126484.aspx

Comment: So I generate this file, it will help IntelliSense or the compiler to discover my collection methods?

Comment: You'd basically automate the tedious process of writing all the extension methods. The result is a C# file that you generate and which is included in your C# project, so you can call the methods as if you'd written them by hand.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. So when that file is generated? At compile time?

Comment: Whenever you change the little C# program generating the file, or when you right-click and and select "Run Custom Tool".

Comment: How would it be different than having another console app that creates a CS file which is already in the VS solution? Would it be the same?

Either way I bet you can get it run at every solution compile.

Comment: A console application would, of course, work too. I think the TextTemplatingFileGenerator is slightly more elegant, but that's just my unfounded opinion. Here's slightly less scary introduction to text templating: http://blogs.msdn.com/davidebb/archive/2009/07/17/two-ways-to-use-t4-templates-support-code-vs-one-time-generation.aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280748/how-to-add-a-dependency-to-a-arbitrary-file-to-a-t4-template

Answer (score 2):

You may find [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/miah/archive/2008/02/22/parallel-extensions-for-net-part-1.aspx) to be an interesting read.  It discusses how a parallel foreach might work, both doing it yourself and using the [Parallel extensions CTP](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=348F73FD-593D-4B3C-B055-694C50D2B0F3&displaylang=en) for .NET 3.5.  With the CTP, you can do this (example taken from article above):

```
using System.Threading;

// A simple string collection
string[] numbers = { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven",
  "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Eleven", "Twelve", "Thirteen", "Fourteen", "Fifteen"};

// equivalent to: foreach (string n in numbers)
Parallel.ForEach<string>(numbers, delegate(string n)
{
  Console.WriteLine("n={0}", n.ToString());
});
```

You should hesitate to use a CTP in production code, unless it's just for your own projects (in which case you should probably want to try CTPs).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple class that iterates in a parallel fashion.

Emre Aydinceren

Usage:

*Parallel.ForEach(matters, matter=> matter.Burn() );*

or

*matters.ParallelForEach(matter=> matter.Burn());*

```
/// <summary>
/// Provides concurrent processing on a sequence of elements
/// </summary>
public static class Parallel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Number Of parallel tasks 
    /// </summary>
    public static int NumberOfParallelTasks;


    static Parallel()
    {
        NumberOfParallelTasks =  Environment.ProcessorCount < 65 ?  Environment.ProcessorCount : 64;  
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Performs the specified action on each element of the sequence in seperate threads.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the elements of source.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="source">A sequence that contains elements to perform action</param>
    /// <param name="action">The Action delegate to perform on each element of the IEnumerable.</param>
    public static void ForEach<T>( IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> action )
    {
        if(source == null) return;

        //create a new stack for parallel task we want to run  , stack is very performant to add and read elements in sequence
        var stacks = new Stack<T>[NumberOfParallelTasks]; 

        //instantiate stacks
        for(var i = 0;i < NumberOfParallelTasks;i++)
        {
            stacks[i] = new Stack<T>();
        }

        var itemCount = 0;

        //spread items in source to all stacks while alternating between stacks
        foreach(var item in source)
        {
            stacks[itemCount++ % NumberOfParallelTasks].Push(item);
        }

        if(itemCount==0)return;

        //if we have less items than number of Parallel tasks we should only spun threads for active stacks
        var activeStackCount = itemCount < NumberOfParallelTasks ? itemCount : NumberOfParallelTasks;

        //events are used to notify thread pool completed
        var events = new ManualResetEvent[activeStackCount];

        for(var index = 0;index < activeStackCount;index++)
        {
            //assign index to a scope variable otherwise in multithreading index will not be consistant
            var listIndex = index;

            events[listIndex] = new ManualResetEvent(false); 

            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate
            {
                //name the thread for debugging
                if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Thread.CurrentThread.Name))
                {
                    Thread.CurrentThread.Name = String.Format("Parallel.ForEach Worker Thread No:{0}", listIndex);
                }

                try
                {   
                    //iterate through our stack 
                    var stack = stacks[listIndex];
                    foreach(var item in stack)
                    {
                        action(item); 
                    }   
                }
                finally
                {
                    //fire the event to signal WaitHandle that our thread is completed
                    events[listIndex].Set();
                }

            });
        }

        WaitAll(events);

    }

    private static void WaitAll(WaitHandle[] waitHandles)
    {
        if(Thread.CurrentThread.GetApartmentState() == ApartmentState.STA)
        {
            for(var index = 0;index < waitHandles.Length;index++) WaitHandle.WaitAny(waitHandles);
        }
        else
        {
            WaitHandle.WaitAll(waitHandles); 
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Performs the specified action on each element of the sequence in seperate threads.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the elements of source.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="source">A sequence that contains elements to perform action</param>
    /// <param name="action">The Action delegate to perform on each element of the IEnumerable.</param>
    public static void  ParallelForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> action)
    {
        ForEach(source, action);
    }

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be just one concurrency aware stack of tasks and a pool of threads. As each thread starts, it checks the stack for work. If the stack is empty it exits. This way is some jobs are long and some are short, you don't end up with one thread running 10 fast jobs and exiting and other running 10 slow jobs all by itself.

Answer (score 0):

create your own ForEachParallel extension then if you dont want to use PLinq or something